# SQL database login for 'Config' on instance '' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, sql-server-2012

In our internet farm in search server I saw below errors in event viewer. How to solve these issues.

> SQL database login for SPL_Config' on instance 'SQL123_SQL' failed.

Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

> Login failed for user 'dc1L\Server1LSEARCH$'.

for the search service application I am using dedicated domain account for search service application service account.

Comment: Is below answer helps you to resolve your issue?

Comment: Is that solution works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change permission for `SharePoint_Config` database, you can do as follows:

1. Login to **SQL Server Management Studio** under **Database Engine** using **authorized login account**.
2. Expand **Security** tree and then r-click on **Logins** > **New Login**
3. Click **Search** and then type your new login account (remember that you must use fully structure domain_name\user_name)
4. After creating new login account, expand **Databases** tree, r-click on `SharePoint_Config` database and then select **Properties**.
5. Click **Permission** setting, select account and then select permission you want to assign for account.

**Another Resolution**

This error occurs because the SharePoint Timer service cannot log on to the SharePoint_Config database on the instance of Microsoft SQL Server that is used by SharePoint. To deploy Microsoft Dynamics NAV Portal Framework, Microsoft Dynamics NAV Setup creates a SharePoint Timer job through the SharePoint application programming interface (API). The SharePoint Timer must have access to the SharePoint_Config database.

To resolve this issue, add the logon account of the SharePoint Timer service as a user of the SharePoint_Config database. Give role membership to the account db_owner.

Comment: For search service account which permissions need on sharepoint_config database? and seach databases?

Comment: It should be DB_Owner

Comment: Is that working for you?