# large number of failed login attempts

Tags: 2013

We're seeing a large number of failed login attempts in SQL for databases that do not exist. These login requests are originating from the **Sharepoint** server and attempting to use the **SA** user login.

When database does not  exist in SQL Server,then how to delete it and why they request it.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179904/sql-database-login-for-config-on-instance-failed-additional-error-informat

Comment: Open a SharePoint PowerShell and enter `Get-SPDatabase | select name,type`. Post the affected databases in your question. Then we can help you to get rid of them.