# SQL database login for 'ConfigDB' on instance ' failed. + Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Tags: configuration, database, login, database-connection

I know my question is very similar to this one;
[SQL database login for 'Config' on instance '' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179904/sql-database-login-for-config-on-instance-failed-additional-error-informat)

However in my case the user is **NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON**.

Complete Error Message:

> SQL database login for 'SharePoint2016_Intranet_ConfigDB' on instance
>   'SQLServer_1' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is
>   included below.  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I am new to SharePoint Administration. And thus *don't know what it will mean giving permission to Anonymous Logon.*

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Have you added any warm up script in Task scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permssion. check couple of things.

1. Check if SharePoint Timer Services is running with "Local System"
   account? Changed it to Domain Account(farm admin) with necessary
   rights will fixed this issue.
2. In an another case, "Windows SharePoint Services VSS Writer" service
   was running with local system account, and I had to change the
   account to a service account from AD.

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/02/event-id-3351-sql-database-login-failed.html#ixzz5Es7w90f9

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thanks for the response. We have 4 servers (2 WFE and 2 APP). Checked "SP Timer Service" on all 4 servers. It is running through Farm Admin account. Regarding "Windows SharePoint Services VSS Writer" AKA "SharePoint VSS Writer" is not running. It's Startup is set to Manual. Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: whats the frequency of the error in your event log? is it on all servers or only one?